# GUI missing in my highcharts-angular version of stock-tools-gui demo

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to make an Angular version of the nice demo: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/stock-tools-gui .

I use the official highcharts-angular wrapper in my attempt here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pjkqwwmkr7  - it works except the GUI elements are not showing. What did I miss? Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI is Highcharts **module**, so remember to import all modules and initialize them like that:

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import * as HIndicatorsAll from "highcharts/indicators/indicators-all";
import * as HDragPanes from "highcharts/modules/drag-panes";
import * as HAnnotationsAdvanced from "highcharts/modules/annotations-advanced";
import * as HPriceIndicator from "highcharts/modules/price-indicator";
import * as HFullScreen from "highcharts/modules/full-screen";
import * as HStockTools from "highcharts/modules/stock-tools";

HIndicatorsAll(Highcharts);
HDragPanes(Highcharts);
HAnnotationsAdvanced(Highcharts);
HPriceIndicator(Highcharts);
HFullScreen(Highcharts);
HStockTools(Highcharts);
```

More about loading modules in `highcharts-angular`: 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-module

Also, note that GUI requires **CSS files** (gui.css, popup.css - I copied files content to styles.css in the codesandbox demo, but it is a better idea to import them).

**Demo:** 
https://codesandbox.io/s/w6ojm7rz0l

Answer (score 0):

You are using Highcharts 6.1.0 which didn't had the stock tools yet. This module have been created for the 7.x version - [Change log](https://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog#highstock-v7.0.0)

Update the version in the codeSandbox and it should works.

`https://code.highcharts.com/modules/stock-tools.js // version 7.x`

`https://code.highcharts.com/6.1.0/modules/stock-tools.js // error`

Comment: Thank you. I have updated all dependencies in the codeSandbox. Now HighCharts is version 7.0.1. Unfortunately it still does not work.